Knowing $a,b,c>0$ and $abc\le1$, prove that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge1+\frac{6}{a+b+c}$
Knowing $a,b,c>0$ and $abc\le1$, prove that $\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge1+\frac{6}{a+b+c}$
I tried to AM-GM the inequality, which gave this:
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge3\sqrt[3]{\frac}{1}{abc}\ge3$$
This, however, didn't lead me anywhere. Probably, I had to take Tittu of this, but:
$$\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}\ge\frac{(1+1+1)^2}{a+b+c}=\frac{9}{a+b+c}$$
This didn't bring me anywhere, either. Any other help is welcomed.

Well, based on your results above $\frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{c} \geq \max\left{3, \frac{9}{a+b+c} \right} \geq \frac{1}{3} \cdot 3 + \frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{9}{a+b+c} = 1 + \frac{6}{a +b+c}$. This might not be the most efficient way but it does the job.

I assume $a,\ b,\ c>0$.
For $a,\ b,\ c>0$ and $abc\leq1$, $\frac1{abc}\geq1$ and $\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{abc}}\geq1$.
Also note that $a>b \land\ c>d\implies(a+c)>(b+d)$.
Now, by the AM-GM inequality:
$$\frac1a+\frac1b+\frac1c\geq3\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{abc}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt[3]{abc}}+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1}{abc}}\geq\frac{2\cdot3}{a+b+c}+1=1+\frac6{a+b+c}.$$

You don’t need the AM-GM inequality, only Cauchy-Schwarz.
The trick here is to find the 2 relevant vectors that when substituted into C.W, gives you precisely the answer.
(Hint: the vectors need to have some algebraic variation of a,b and c in their inputs, consider $\sqrt a$,$\sqrt b$,$\sqrt c$ or their inverse.)

My bad, corrected the typo.
